# How can I remove (.remove) all elements (div) but not this (this) element (div) in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, onclick

I have a set of divs listening for a click.  When one is clicked I need to remove all the others.

HTML:

```
<div class="foo">A</div>
<div class="foo">B</div>
<div class="foo">C</div>
<div class="foo">D</div>
```

If I click div (A), how can I remove all the rest (B,C,D) but keep A?

I tried this, but it didn't work:

```
$('.foo:not(this)').remove();
```

Comment: Can I assume the ones you are removing are the siblings to the one you want to keep?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$('.foo').not(this).remove(); //w00t
```

So to put it all together:

```
$('.foo').click(function(){ 
    //code...
    $('.foo').not(this).remove(); //w00t
    //more code....
});
```

Answer (score 2):

***IF*** you are trying to remove all the siblings of a set of elements, you can do this.

```
$(".foo").click(function (e) {
    $(this).siblings().remove();
});
```

Comment: Why are _assuming_ that the other `.foo`'s are siblings?

Comment: If they are siblings, then this approach is correct. The HTML provided gives that indication. Of course, if they are not siblings then this won't work, but it's a common-enough use-case to remove all an element's siblings.

Comment: You know what happens when you _assume_?

Comment: When Ryan answers my comment, I will gladly remove my answer if it does not apply. Besides, I clearly started my answer with *if* :\

Comment: ***IF*** :-P remember that ;-)

Comment: LOL.  Thanks.  Yes, they are siblings, but for my purposes the .foo works just fine.